# checking if pandas dataframe is indexed?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to check if a pandas dataframe is indexed? Check if `DataFrame.set_index(...)` was ever called on the dataframe? I could check if `df.index` is a numeric list but that's not a perfect test for this.

Comment: When you say check if it is "indexed" do you mean check if the index is not the default range(n)?

Comment: @TomAugspurger: I meant if it was ever called because if you have a csv file with first column 1,2,3,... and you call `set_index` on that it will be indistinguishable from the default index, but it's still important for me to know if it was indexed or not because I am doing a merge operation that relies on an indexed dataframe

Comment: what do you mean by "indexed" and how does merge operation rely on it?

Comment: @AndyHayden: I am using `concat` to concat columns of two dataframes together and I want to avoid concatenating together two dataframes that are not indexed that's all. indexed I mean dataframes where the user explicitly assigned a unique column identifying each row to the dataframe with `set_index`. maybe this is impossible to tell?

Comment: Can't you just call set_index(column) again before doing the merge?  If you're worried that the index isn't there anymore because it's been moved to the index you can do a try: except KeyError:

Comment: @TomAugsburger: good point but if you're writing a generic merge function you don't know what column the user wanted to merge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to compare it to the plain Index:

```
pd.Index(np.arange(0, len(df))).equals(df.index)
```

For example:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  a  b
1  c  d

In [13]: pd.Index(np.arange(0, len(df))).equals(df.index)
Out[13]: True
```

and if it's not the plain index, it will return False:

```
In [14]: df = df.set_index('A')

In [15]: pd.Index(np.arange(0, len(df))).equals(df.index)
Out[15]: False
```

Comment: Unless of course someone called df.set_index(np.arange(0, len(df))) :).  I'm a bit confused by the question, if he's really asking of "`set_index` was ever called on the dataframe"

Comment: @TomAugspurger: exactly, i want to distinguish the two cases

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this myself. The problem is that a dataframe *is* indexed *before* calling `.set_index()`, so the question is really whether or not the index is *named*. In which case, `df.index.name` appears to be less reliable than `df.index.names`

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"id1": [1, 2, 3], "id2": [4,5,6], "word": ["cat", "mouse", "game"]})
>>> df
   id1  id2   word
0    1    4    cat
1    2    5  mouse
2    3    6   game
>>> df.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
>>> df.index.name, df.index.names[0]
(None, None)
>>> "indexed" if df.index.names[0] else "no index"
'no index'
>>> df1 = df.set_index("id1")
>>> df1
     id2   word
id1            
1      4    cat
2      5  mouse
3      6   game
>>> df1.index
>>> df1.index.name, df1.index.names[0]
('id1', 'id1')
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64', name='id1')
>>> "indexed" if df1.index.names[0] else "no index"
'indexed'
>>> df12 = df.set_index(["id1", "id2"])
>>> df12
          word
id1 id2       
1   4      cat
2   5    mouse
3   6     game
>>> df12.index
MultiIndex([(1, 4),
            (2, 5),
            (3, 6)],
           names=['id1', 'id2'])
>>> df12.index.name, df12.index.names[0]
(None, 'id1')
>>> "indexed" if df12.index.names[0] else "no index"
'indexed'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, I do set_index([label], append=False) if the dataframe has the default RangeIndex, or set_index([label], append=True) otherwise.

```py
append = not isinstance(df.index, pd.RangeIndex)
df.set_index([label], drop=True, append=append, inplace=True)
```

So my assumption, is that when index is the default RangeIndex, that setting another column as an index, I can drop the RangeIndex.